# Хочу сделать случайные размеры фракталов в консоли, как сделать разницу в более 15 единиц, это интересно

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу сделать случайные фракталы, что будут выводиться в консоли, но не могу придумать как сделать разницу как минимум в 15 единиц, чтобы высота точки c была менее чем 15 единиц например от крайней точки ya и yb.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы была разница от края точки в 15 единиц и более?

```
    Console.Clear();

string s = "x";

int yb = new Random().Next(15, 46);
int yc = new Random().Next(15, 46);
int xc = new Random().Next(14, 150);
int xa = new Random().Next(4, 150);

int ya = 4, xb = 4;

Console.SetCursorPosition(xa, ya);
Console.Write(s);

Console.SetCursorPosition(xb, yb);
Console.Write(s);

Console.SetCursorPosition(xc, yc);
Console.Write(s); 

int x = xa, y = xb;

int count = 0;
while (count < 1000) {
    int nr  = new Random().Next(0, 3); // 0 1 2
    if (nr == 0){
        x = (x + xa) / 2;
        y = (y + ya) / 2; 
    } 
    if (nr == 1){
        x = (x + xb) / 2;
        y = (y + yb) / 2; 
    } 
    if (nr == 2){
        x = (x + xc) / 2;
        y = (y + yc) / 2; 
    } 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.Write(s);
    count++;
}
```

А так код работает прекрасно, но иногда вылезает ошибка из-за отсутствия разницы. Есть идея чтобы при ошибке код запускался заново, но это немного колхоз)
Нужно чтобы треугольник не был слишком "тонким" или "узким", для этого я думаю, что стоит сделать
минимальный порог разницы от одной координаты точки к другой. Допустим точка координат ya не может быть отделена от yc всего в 1 переход к новой строки, нужно как минимум 15, в общем это вся проблема.
В идеале код должен выводиться как-то так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но не иметь подобный проблем:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поправьте вопрос, напишите код в виде текста а не картинке.

Comment: Не надо делать `new Random` на каждый чих. Создайте его один раз `Random rnd = new();` и далее `rnd.Next` вызывайте. Ну или если совсем не хочется, то хотя-бы используйте `Random.Shared.Next`.

Comment: Да это поправимо, но главный вопрос остаётся, это я поправил 
Random rnd = new();
int yb = rnd.Next(15, 46);

Comment: В этом коде не видно причины исключения. То есть результат работы на скриншоте не соответствует показанному коду. Так же вы не уточнили, каким конкрентно образом добились первого и второго результата. А как по-вашему возможно починить то, что вы тщательно от нас скрываете? Этот вопрос подлежит закрытию, исправляйте.